# Sending batches of data to fit_generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, generator

I want to pass a generator to fit_generator, which shall yield multidimensional arrays x and y in batches. x is of dimension (1000000, 200) and y is of (1000000, 2000). I'm doing frame-by-frame classification. My current code looks like this:

```
def my_generator():

    current = 0
    batch_size = 500
    for i in range(current, 1000000, batch_size):
        x_batch =x[i, :]
        y_batch=y[i, :]
        yield(x_batch, y_batch)

model.fit_generator(generator=(my_generator()), steps_per_epoch=2000, epochs=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

But I do not believe I'm sending the fit_generator function the correct dimensions of batches or that my code isn't right. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're taking batches of size 1 from `x` and `y`. To get full-sized batches, change these lines

```
        x_batch = x[i, :]
        y_batch = y[i, :]
```

to this

```
        x_batch = x[i:i + batch_size, :]
        y_batch = y[i:i + batch_size, :]
```

This will take a slice from `i` up to (but not including) `i + batch_size`, rather than just taking a single-array slice.